# Iterate twice through an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an iterable object, and when I do 1 loop it is okay, but when doing multiple loops, it doesn't work. Here is my simplified code:

```
class test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n < len(self)-1:
            self.n += 1
            return self.n
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __len__(self):
        return 5

#this is an example iteration
test = test()
for i in test:
    for j in test:
        print(i,j)

#it prints is 
1 2
1 3
1 4

#What i expect is
1 1 
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
...
4 3
4 4
```

How can I make this object (in this case `test`) to iterate twice and get all the combinations of number `i` and `j` in the example loop?

Comment: You're iterating over the *same iterator*, which can only be consumed once; use `for i in test(): for j in test(): print(i, j)` instead. If you really need to share a single iterator, look into e.g. [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

Comment: If you use something like `test = [1,2,3]` for your loops, it works because a list is not an *iterator*, but it is an *iterable*. In that case, each `for` loop implicitly calls `iter` to get a distinct iterator for the list. Your `test` class *is* an iterator, since it defines `__next__`, so each loop uses the same iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an instance of `test` to be *iterable*, but not its own *iterator*. What's the difference?

An iterable is something that, upon request, can supply an iterator. Lists are iterable, because `iter([1,2,3])` returns a new `listiterator` object (*not* the list itself). To make `test` iterable, you just need to supply an `__iter__` method (more on how to define it in a bit).

An iterator is something that, upon request, can produce a new element. It does this by calling its `__next__` method. An iterator can be thought of as two pieces of information: a sequence of items to produce, and a cursor indicating how far along that sequence it currently is. When it reaches the end of its sequence, it raises a `StopIteration` exception to indicate that the iteration is at an end. To make an instance an iterator, you supply a `__next__` method in its class. An iterator should also have a `__iter__` method that just returns itself.

So how do you make `test` iterable without being an iterator? By having its `__iter__` method return a new iterator each time it is called, and getting rid of its `__next__` method. The simplest way to do that is to make `__iter__` a generator function. Define your class something like:

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self._size = 5

    def __iter__(self):
        n = 0
        while n < self._size:
            yield n
            n += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size
```

Now when you write

```
test = Test()
for i in test:    # implicit call to iter(test)
    for j in test:  # implicit call to iter(test)
        print(i, j)
```

`i` and `j` both draw values from *separate* iterators over the same iterable. Each call to `test.__iter__` returns a different generator object that keeps track of its own `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

You should be able to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
from itertools import product
...
test = test()
for i, j in product(test, repeat=2):
    print(i,j)
```

I love this library!